# Lock the position of desktop icon 14.03

Tags: command-line, icons, security, directory, lock

I was wondering if there is a way to prevent a user from moving a desktop icon but it still be usable? I am on ubuntu 14.03 32 bit. Any help wnd suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Would you find a (lightweight) background script that simply immediately *restores* an icon arrangement you took a snapshot of (in case icons are moved) as an acceptable solution? I could easily combine this one: http://askubuntu.com/a/618450/72216 and this one: http://askubuntu.com/a/628031/72216 into a functional background script that works as described. with some optimization, it would not add noticable background activity.

Comment: Dee, did you notice my question? Please let me know.

Comment: Hi Dee, I never noticed your comment, since you posted it... as an answer! Please delete the answer and post it as a comment to your question. You can also @ping a person if you want to make sure the person will notice. Preventing an icon from adding it to the Unity Launcher or preventing deletion is another story however, with another solution. What is your priority?

Answer (score 0):

there is a Nautilus script that can save/restore the ubuntu 14.04 desktop icon positions. It also has the ability to align all of the icons ..

It can be downloaded at gnome-look.org and is named "Happy Desktop"

just google it.