# How can I troubleshoot why my Desktop wallpaper is not being changed?

Tags: unity, desktop-background

I changed the Desktop wallpaper but the default one from Ubuntu 16.04 is still being shown. How can I troubleshoot and debug why changing the default wallpaper does not work?

**Screenshot:**

[image: Wallpaper settings]

According to the command-line output, the custom wallpaper is being applied but for some reasons not shown.

[image: Wallpaper preview Nautilus]

**Command-line:**

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
'file:///home/orschiro/Pictures/Wallpapers/zen.jpg'
```

Comment: Does it work with any other wallpaper image?

Comment: Did you try restarting your computer? Also, try gdm-restart.

Comment: i believe the desktop background  is handled by nautilus , try browsing to the file with nautilus and check it can be thumbnailed, if not its possible nautilus is having trouble opening it.

Comment: Is this your first time trying to change wallpaper on this system?

Comment: @Jos it doesn't work with any wallpaper, unfortunately. I did try restarting my computer. The command `gdm-restart` cannot be found. The image can be thumbnailed. I updated my question. Yes, it's the first time I am trying to change my wallpaper on this system.

Comment: The new wallpaper is, however, shown and used as the background for the login screen.

Comment: Dear all, please take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from [How to configure GNOME 3 to show icons on desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43246/how-to-configure-gnome-3-to-show-icons-on-desktop).

The custom wallpaper is only shown if the following is being set true:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

**My ultimate question: Is it not possible to hide Desktop icons but use a custom wallpaper?**