# Network file shares not appearing in GNOME or any DE

Tags: networking, ftp, file-sharing

but they can be accessed via the ftp command in the terminal and via a a file transfer utility such as Filezilla. They don't even show up in GNOME after I've moved files between my computer and my networked file share (in this case, a Seagate 1TB hard drive connected to a TP-Link Archer C8 router). Any help with this one folks?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you want sorry, but I like adding my network file shares to my `/etc/fstab` (file system table file), then I just reference them via directory. Some of mine are accessed using 'auto'  (loaded on boot), others are mounted by script (ie. unmounted by default, mounted only for backup purposes; `umount` when done).  None of mine show up on my DE, but I can navigate to them using any file manager (using their mounted directories)

Comment: Are you talking about the icons showing up in the Desktop itself?  GNOME doesn't have the ability to show Desktop Icons on it by default.  You would have to do it with GNOME Tweak for them to show up.  I do know that Xfce4 (Xubuntu), LXDE (Lubuntu) and KDE (Kubuntu) all can show Desktop Icons by default without using any tweaks.  Or see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/43246/how-to-configure-gnome-3-to-show-icons-on-desktop

Comment: Talking about Nautilus/Nemo file manager. Network shares not showing up in that and I don't know how to access them in there directly.